# Задать имя селектору с помощью переменной в SCSS

Tags: scss, css

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите, как можно задать имя селектору с помощью переменной?
Или каким-то другим способом, главное, что бы изменив имя в одном месте оно менялось в остальных частях кода.

Вот пример кода:

```
$name: '.my_element';

$name {
  background-color: $bg_color;
  color: $text_color;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**update**
А на самом деле всё намного проще:

```
$name: '.my_element';
$bg_color: #DDDDDD;
$text_color: #FFFFFF;

#{$name} {
  background-color: $bg_color;
  color: $text_color;
}
```

Я думаю Вам поможет что то типа такого:

Mixins

Even more powerful than variables, mixins allow you to re-use whole chunks of CSS, properties or selectors. You can even give them arguments.

```
@mixin table-scaffolding {
  th {
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  td, th { padding: 2px; }
}

@mixin left($dist) {
  float: left;
  margin-left: $dist;
}

#data {
  @include left(10px);
  @include table-scaffolding;
}
```

В вашем случае это будет так:

```
@mixin name($selector) {
     #{$selector}
    {
      background-color: $bg_color;
      color: $text_color;
    } 
}

@include name(".my_element");

@include name(".your_element");
```

Comment: It works!) Спасибо.